# Filter instances by state with boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3

Trying to use boto3 to describe all of my instances and filter every instance that is not currently running.
Using this post as a reference for building my filter - http://rob.salmond.ca/filtering-instances-by-name-with-boto3/.

When I try to filter the instances by state using this filter -

```
filters = [{
'Name': 'tag:State',
'Values': ['running']
}]
```

The query comes back empty (which makes sense, since the state value is nested inside a dictionary of it's own.

My question is - how do I access a nested tag with the filters parameter?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
session = boto3.Session(region_name="us-east-1")

ec2 = session.resource('ec2', region)

instances = ec2.instances.filter(
        Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped', 'terminated']}])

for instance in instances:
    print(instance.id, instance.instance_type)
```

**Hope it helps !!**

Comment: Filtering this way calls: `boto3.resources.collection (DEBUG): Calling paginated ec2:describe_instances`. How can pagination be handled here?

Comment: this is relying on the proper spelling of "stopped" and "terminated".  Assuming you can use instance-state-code and 48 and 80... is there a way to get the values 48 and 80 from some kind of lookup or name?  That way if you misspell stopped you'll get an attribute error and not silently fail and give false positives/negatives?  For instance boto3.some_package.ec2states.stopped.

Problem is that the ec2.instances.filter doesn't complain if you give it a typo.  I want Python itself to complain about an attribute if I have a typo